# Using React Hooks on a legacy web page gives "Invalid hook call" error message

Tags: visual-studio, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a react component that runs on an existing HTML page of a legacy web application (aspx webforms in visual studio):

```html
<div id="my-div" data-first-prop="1" data-second-prop="2"></div>
```

But I want to use the functions and "Hooks" approach, not the older Component classes.

components/Page.tsx:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Page(props) {
  // const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        props: {props.firstProp} and {props.secondProp}!
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Page;
```

index.tsx:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import Page from './components/page';

const container = document.getElementById('my-div');
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <Page
    firstProp={container.getAttribute('data-first-prop')}
    secondProp={container.getAttribute('data-second-prop')}
  />
);
```

This code runs fine, but when I uncommented line 10 to get state:

```js
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

...I get the infamous "Invalid hook call" error message:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of
> the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem.

I've been all through that linked help page with no success. Running

```
npm link node_modules/react
```

Just gives me git-related error messages. (?)

It might be multiple versions of react, when I run

```
npm ls react
```

I get:

```
+-- react-dom@18.1.0
| `-- react@18.1.0 deduped
`-- react@18.1.0
```

But I've got no clue what that means, where any of those are, or how to fix that.

Can anyone give me a hint on what to do about duplicates, or see what else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this an accurate representation of the React code you are injecting into the existing web page? I don't see any overt issues with it in isolation. Do you see the same react hooks issue if you run your app separately from the existing page?

Comment: The code itself looks fine. It's likely an issue with how you've set up the project. Can you check which version of `react-dom` you've got installed? It should also be `18.1.0`. If that's the case, then maybe it's an issue with how `react` is resolved by your bundler, e.g. if you have a monorepo with multiple `node_modules` folders and multiple copies of React, or some peer dependency that's not installed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The way you invoke rendering your component while appearing neat and syntactically correct, somehow confuses React:

```
root.render(CustomQuestionPage(props));
```

You need to change it to:

```
root.render(<CustomQuestionPage
             firstProp={container.getAttribute('data-first-prop')} 
             secondProp={container.getAttribute('data-second-prop')}
            />);
```

You can use this sample [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/props-from-root-fg2z66-fg2z66?file=/src/index.js) for reference.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this does not change anything for my code. I still get the same "Invalid hook call" error message on that useState(0) line. (I tried copying and pasting your working code from the sandbox into my web app with some minor changes to get it to build, still no change. It works without that line, but fails if it's in. And I need state).

Comment: Do you have any other places in your app where you invoke your component(s) as function(s)? Doing this somehow causes a sort of "short-circuit" in React and it doesn't mount the component properly.

Comment: Not this component, but there are several other components, mostly class components, in my app. Do you think I might need to change them all to function components/hooks or it won't work?

Comment: Using class and function components in the same app should not be a problem, but you cannot use hooks in class components. You can see what component causes the error message  by putting a breakpoint in the `printWarning` function (click on the link next to the error message in the console) and then looking at the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

You never use the empty state, I'd either initialize it like this

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(props);
```

or this

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(props.firstProp);
```

Or at least increasing the zero value and using the result.
Actually it's a wild guess that this will change something.
Here is the example with zero value: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html